# Does stackoverflow uses any ajax push?

Tags: discussion, live-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Does stackoverflow.com uses any push engine to push the data to the browser?  It is extremely fast.  Anyone who know the details please let me know.  In which language it has been done?

Comment: I remember reading here that it uses Websockets.

Comment: The site is coded in C#, as well as HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. I can't remember what type of database they use though.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: That's the thing about JavaScript, you can never hide it from the user.  Just use your favorite DOM inspector and see what SO is using.   They're already showing you all of their code as plain text.